Euler system definition, $\text{Cor}_{F'/F}(c_{F'})=(\prod_{q : \text{primes of K} }P({Fr_q}^{-1}\mid T^* ; {Fr_q}^{-1}))・c_F$
Let $K$ be a number field, $O$ be the ring of integers of a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $T$ be a free $O$-module of finite rank with a continuous action of $G_K$ which is unramified at almost every place.
An Euler system is (essentially – see Definition 2.1.1 of Rubin’s Euler Systems available here for the details) a collection of cohomology classes $c_F \in H^1(F,T)$, where $F$ runs over certain finite Abelian extensions of $K$, satisfying, for any finite Abelian $F,F’/K$ with $F’ \supset F$ the following norm relation:
$$\mathrm{Cor}_{F'/F}(c_{F'})=(\prod_{q \text{ prime of } K}P({Fr_q}^{-1}\mid T^* ; {Fr_q}^{-1}))\cdot c_F.$$
Here, the set of $q$ over which the above product is taken is somewhat flexible (again, see Rubin’s text for details), but it never contains a prime above $p$, and only contains primes of $K$ that ramify in $F’$ but not in $F$.
My question is the following: what does the above $\cdot$ mean?
Here, $P({Fr_q}^{-1}\mid T^* ; x))$ is defined in the text as $\mathrm{det}(1-Fr_q^{-1}x\mid T^*)\in  O[x]$, but I don't know the definition of $P({Fr_q}^{-1}\mid T^* ; {Fr_q}^{-1}))$.
My questions are,

What is a definition of $P({Fr_q}^{-1}\mid T^* ; {Fr_q}^{-1}))$ and where does this element belong?

What does $\cdot$ mean?



See “page 34, Definition 2.1.1” of what?

Let $\Pi(x) \in O[x]$ denote the polynomial $\det(1-Fr_q^{-1}x \mid T^{\ast})$. It’s a polynomial like any other.
Then $P(Fr_q^{-1}\mid T^{\ast};Fr_q^{-1})$ denotes the element $\Pi(Fr_q^{-1})$. So if, say, $\Pi(X)=X^2+3$, then $P(Fr_q^{-1}\mid T^{\ast};Fr_q^{-1})=Fr_q^{-2}+3$.
This element lives in the algebra $O[Gal(F/K)]$ (recall that $F/K$ is Abelian).
The point is that $O[Gal(F/K)]$ acts on $H^1(F,T)$. One possible interpretation of this action is as follows (of course, there’s a better interpretation in terms of homological algebra but I don’t want to get into the details).
The group $H^1(F,T)$ is the quotient of cocycles (maps $f: G_F \rightarrow T$ with $f(uv)=f(u)+u\cdot f(v)$) by coboundaries (maps $f: G_F \rightarrow T$ of the form $f(u)=u \cdot m-m$ for some $m \in T$).
Now, the set of cocycles has an action of $O[G_K]$ as follows: the action of $O$ is its action on $T$, and the action of $\sigma \in G_K$ is by $(\sigma \cdot f): u \in G_F \mapsto \sigma\left[f(\sigma^{-1}u\sigma)\right] \in T$.
You can check that this action preserves coboundaries, so becomes an action of $O[G_K]$ on $H^1(F,T)$. Next, you can check that the action of $G_F$ on $H^1(F,T)$ is trivial, and you thus see $H^1(F,T)$ as a $O[Gal(F/K)]$-module.

Thank you very much ! May I ask just two questions regarding this matter?  1.  Is the following understanding ok ?  Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a normal finite index subgroup of $G$.
$G/H$ act on $H^1(H,M)$ by $(\overline{g}*X)(h)=gX(g^{-1}hg)$. In this case, $G=G_K$ and $H=G_F$ gives the desired action.

I would like to confirm: what is the size of the matrix for which we are taking the determinant?



Yes, 2) we’re taking the determinant of an endomorphism (of $T^{\ast}$), not directly of a matrix. If you really want to view this in terms of matrices, then its size would be the rank of $T^{\ast}$.

